# How to find json data?

Tags: json, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

chitown88 help me to find the json on this website : https://www.iwc.com/fr/fr/watch-collections/pilot-watches/iw329303-big-pilots-watch-43.html

It seems that you need to replace `html` by `.productinfo.FR.json`

Source : [How to scrape specific information on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784965/how-to-scrape-specific-information-on-a-website/71785186?noredirect=1#comment126862321_71785186)

I would like to do the same output with this page : https://www.omegawatches.com/fr-fr/watch-omega-constellation-quartz-27-mm-12315276005001

But I cannot manage to scrape those informations because the page is dynamic and I cannot find the json data, I searched for hours.

Do you have any solutions in order to scrape the same output than the question source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything special about this page. Just grab the right information with `beautifulsoup`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.omegawatches.com/fr-fr/watch-omega-constellation-quartz-27-mm-12315276005001"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

title = soup.title.text.split("|")[0].strip()
description = soup.select_one(".description-content").get_text(strip=True)
price = soup.select_one(".price").text
info = "\n".join(
    tag.get_text(strip=True)
    for tag in soup.select(
        ".product-info-details-right .li, .product-info-details-right li"
    )
)

print(title)
print()
print(description)
print("-" * 80)
print(price)
print("-" * 80)
print(info)
```

Prints:

```
Constellation Quartz 27 mm - 123.15.27.60.05.001

L'esthétique particulièrement remarquable et intemporelle de la collection OMEGA Constellation  se caractérise par l'originalité du cadran et la présence des fameuses griffes.Ce modèle brossé se distingue par un cadran en nacre blanche protégé par un verre saphir résistant aux rayures. La lunette sertie de diamants est montée sur un boîtier de 27 mm en acier inoxydable sur un bracelet également en acier inoxydable.Cette montre est animée par le calibre OMEGA 1376, un mouvement de précision à quartz.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 000,00 €
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Diamants
Entre‑corne :18 mm
Bracelet :acier
Boîtier :acier
Diamètre du boîtier :27 mm
Couleur du cadran :blanc
Verre :verre saphir bombé résistant aux rayures, traité antireflet à l’intérieur
Étanchéité :10 bars (100 mètres / 330 pieds)
Type de mouvement :quartz
Calibre :OMEGA 1376
Mouvement de précision à quartz, finition rhodiée.
Durée de vie de la pile :48 mois
Type :quartz
Swiss Made
GARANTIE 5 ANS
Paiement sécurisé
Livraison et retour offerts
```